# TCP socket 'server' reading twice input sent once

Tags: c++, tcp

I am try to build an interface for an old ERP (Enterprise resource planning) that is very efficient,
but the customer do not like it so much because it is missing a graphical interface,
the Software is build with a custom language, the source code of the language is C, so that is why i have chosen C and C++ for my project, the GUI will be a Qt app talking to a TCP server written in C, and i will use this to make the two environment communicate with each other.

the problem:

my TCP server is reading the data from my Qt app twice, even if i send it once, and there was garbage data, like if I sent '1' the server was reading 1??:
here is my C code for the server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define MAX_CLIENTS 10
#define BUFFER_SIZE 256

int client_sockets[MAX_CLIENTS] = {0}; // Store client socket fds
pthread_mutex_t client_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void error(const char *msg) {
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

void broadcast_message(char *message, int sender_fd) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&client_mutex);
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CLIENTS; i++) {
        if (client_sockets[i] > 0 && client_sockets[i] != sender_fd) {
            if (write(client_sockets[i], message, strlen(message)) < 0) {
                perror("ERROR writing to socket");
            }
        }
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&client_mutex);
}


int sanitizeData(char *data, int len) {
    int j = 0; // Index for writing sanitized characters
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        if (data[i] >= '0' && data[i] <= '9') {
            data[j++] = data[i]; // Copy numeric character
        }
    }
    data[j] = '\0'; // Null-terminate the sanitized data
    return j; // Return the length of sanitized data
}


void *handleClient(void *socket_desc) {
    int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int n;

    // Client handling loop
    while (1) {
        bzero(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
        n = read(sock, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE - 1); // Leave space for null terminator
        if (n <= 0) {
            if (n < 0) perror("ERROR reading from socket");
            break; // Exit loop on error or disconnect
        }

        printf("raw data recievd: %s\n",buffer);//show the data received from the Qt app.

    n = sanitizeData(buffer,n);

        //buffer[n] = '\0'; // Ensure the buffer is null-terminated
        
    if (n > 0){
        printf("Received (sanitized data): %s\n", buffer);
        // Echo back the received message (or handle as needed)
                broadcast_message(buffer, sock);
    }else{
          printf("no numbers in  the data recived");
    } 
    


    }

    // Cleanup on exit
    close(sock);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&client_mutex);
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CLIENTS; i++) {
        if (client_sockets[i] == sock) {
            client_sockets[i] = 0; // Mark as available
            break;
        }
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&client_mutex);
    free(socket_desc); // Free the allocated memory for the socket descriptor
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno = 3232;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    socklen_t clilen;

    // Create socket
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) error("ERROR opening socket");

    // Bind
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR on binding");

    // Listen
    listen(sockfd, 5);
    printf("Server started on port %d. Waiting for connections...\n", portno);

    // Accept connections loop
    while (1) {
        clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
        newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
        if (newsockfd < 0) error("ERROR on accept");

        pthread_t thread_id;
        int *new_sock = malloc(sizeof(int));
        if (new_sock == NULL) {
            error("ERROR allocating memory for new socket");
        }
        *new_sock = newsockfd;

        if (pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, handleClient, (void*) new_sock) < 0) {
            error("Could not create thread");
        }
        pthread_detach(thread_id); // Optionally detach the thread to free resources upon completion
    }

    return 0; // Typically unreachable
}
```

here i've try to clean the data received from my qt app, because i thought that was the problem, since I've seen garbage data, in a prior version of my code i was printing the data received on the screen and you could see that '1' was received as 1?? or 1?@ and with the number '2' as well. the only number received plain as number was the number '0', which i don't understand why, maybe has something to do with the null char in C string?

I have started with QTcpSocket and then create my custom socket in the Qt app using C++, because I thought the issue of the garbage data was related to the way QTcpSocket was handling data, so i create a Custom_socket class like this :

```
#ifndef CUSTOM_SOCKET_H
#define CUSTOM_SOCKET_H

#include <iostream>
#include <cstring> // For memset
#include <unistd.h> // For close()
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string>






class Custom_Socket {
private:
    std::string serverIp;
    int port;
    int sock = -1; // Initialize socket to an invalid value

public:
    Custom_Socket(const std::string& serverIp, int port)
        : serverIp(serverIp), port(port) {}

    bool connectToServer() {
        // Create socket
        sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (sock == -1) {
            std::cerr << "Could not create socket.\n";
            return false;
        }
        std::cout << "Socket created.\n";

        // Setup server structure
        struct sockaddr_in server;
        memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
        server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(serverIp.c_str());
        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server.sin_port = htons(port);

        // Connect to remote server
        if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
            perror("Connect failed. Error");
            return false;
        }

        std::cout << "Connected to server.\n";
        return true;
    }

    // Add methods for send/recv
    // Method to send data
    bool sendData(const std::string& data) {
        if (send(sock, data.c_str(), data.size(), 0) < 0) {
            perror("Send failed. Error");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    // Method to receive data
    std::string receiveData() {
        char buffer[256];
        std::memset(buffer, 0, 256);
        ssize_t len = recv(sock, buffer, 255, 0);
        if (len < 0) {
            perror("Receive failed. Error");
            return "";
        }
        return std::string(buffer, len);
    }


    ~Custom_Socket() {
        if (sock != -1) {
            close(sock); // Close the socket when done
        }
    }


};




#endif // CUSTOM_SOCKET_H
```

and I am using this socket to connect to the port on the server and sending and reading data.

like so :

```
void mainMenu::on_order_entrt_btn_clicked()
{
    emit navigate_to_widget(1);
    std::string ez_gen_task = "1";

    mainMenu_socket->sendData(ez_gen_task.c_str());

}
```

i also thought that the std::string could cause issues since it is a class of C++ and strings are handled different in C, so I changed to be only one byte like so:

```
void mainMenu::on_order_entrt_btn_clicked()
{
    emit navigate_to_widget(1);
    char ez_gen_task = '1';

    mainMenu_socket->sendData(&ez_gen_task);

}
```

now the garbage data seems gone!
but i still have the issue of the double data received!

the data is received as (this is the output of  printf() from the C server code):

```
raw data recievd: 1
Received (sanitized data): 1
raw data recievd: 1
Received (sanitized data): 1
raw data recievd: 2
Received (sanitized data): 2
raw data recievd: 2
Received (sanitized data): 2
raw data recievd: 0
Received (sanitized data): 0
raw data recievd: 1
Received (sanitized data): 1
raw data recievd: 1
Received (sanitized data): 1
raw data recievd: 2
Received (sanitized data): 2
raw data recievd: 2
Received (sanitized data): 2
raw data recievd: 0
Received (sanitized data): 0
raw data recievd: 0
Received (sanitized data): 0
raw data recievd: 2
Received (sanitized data): 2
raw data recievd: 2
Received (sanitized data): 2
raw data recievd: 0
Received (sanitized data): 0
raw data recievd: 0
Received (sanitized data): 0
raw data recievd: 1
Received (sanitized data): 1
raw data recievd: 1
Received (sanitized data): 1
raw data recievd: 2
Received (sanitized data): 2
raw data recievd: 2
Received (sanitized data): 2
```

now the data seem clean but it is still reading twice the number '1' and the number '2' and only once the number '0' so the number 0 is handled correctly, however I am not understanding why!

thank you for your help, and I apologized before hand if I am missing something stupid, which is almost always the case...

Lorenzo

Comment: You are ignoring the case where `recv()` returns zero.

Comment: It's a stream socket.  There is no one-to-one pairing between `write` and `read`.

Comment: This is not C code. Don’t tag indiscriminately.

Comment: I found out the problem! the slot-signal mechanism in Qt  is what triggered the socket->write(); twice! problem solved. Sorry @user207421, i meant to paste my C code regarding the TCP server, but I forgot.